# Jaxrpc-2.2.jar version mismatch

Tags: jar

I am using jaxb jars of version 2.2 in my project. But the jaxrpc.jar is of different version. it is 1.1. Because of this, I am getting a classCastException in project. Does the 2.2 version jaxrpc is available? or what should I do to clear this error? I am using cxf servlet in my project.

Comment: Libraries have their own versions. So jaxb jar and jaxrpc jar need not have same version. You'll have to check the compatibility of a library that you want to use(jaxb) with libraries that you are already using(jaxrpc).

Comment: Ok. I must use jaxb 2.2 . And jaxrpc is required in my project. If the version is not a matter... naturally the jaxrpc-1.1 (available version) is compactible with the library, right?

Comment: error message : shows java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.gmbal.ManagedObjectManager in the service but the client shows java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl cannot be cast to com.sun.xml.internal.bind.api.JAXBRIContext

Comment: In console (tomcat) it showed a class not found exception-javax.ejb.createException. I have added j2ee.jar to resolve it.